# Show More / Show Less JavaScript not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, show

I am trying to make a div tag appear when I select a "show more" link. So far, the div appears when the page loads, which I don't want. Then when I select the "Show" link, the div disappears. I need the opposite to happen, and then make the div disappear when I select the link again.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="VideoText" align="left">
<a href=""><span> <strong> Credits </strong> </span></a> 
<br> Directed By: <a href="#"> Link One </a>
<br> Edited   By: <a href="#"> Link Two </a>
<br>

<a href="#" id="hideshow">Show</a>

<div id="message">
    Credit: <a href="#"> Link Three </a> <br>
    Credit: <a href="#"> Link Four </a>  <br>

</div>
</div>
```

Here's my .js file:

```
$('#hideshow') .click(function() {
    $('#hideshow') .text('Hide');
    $('#message') .show();
    }, function() {
    $('#hideshow').text('Show');
    $('#message') .hide();

});
```

I feel like I just have some of the code in the wrong place.

Here is the page where I am trying to get the code to work:
http://www.kingdombrand.com/Film/Alek/Films/TestFilm

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/ry5jLcmm/8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this JS:

```
$('#hideshow').click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault()

   if($('#hideshow').text() == 'Show'){
      $('#hideshow').text('Hide');
      $('#message').show();
   }
   else{
      $('#hideshow').text('Show');
      $('#message').hide();
   }
});
```

And this css:

```
#message {
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: this worked perfectly. One other question, when I make the word "show" bold, it then changes to regular font on the first click then the action happens on the second click. Do you know how I can make the result in the javascript, bold, so that the action can work on the first click?

Comment: add this to CSS:

#message {
   display: none;
   font-weight: bold;
}

Answer (score 2):

I would personally hide the `#message` element with CSS:

```
#message {
    display: none;
}
```

Using the above, the element will be hidden by default. So, I'm guessing your code will now work, but I would change it just a bit to something like this:

```
$('#hideshow').click(function() {
    $('#message').toggle();

    if ($(this).text() == 'Show') {
        $(this).text("Hide");
    else
        $(this).text("Show");
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use class to hide the `div` and then use jQuery's [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method to toggle that class on/off.

So in your CSS:

```
.is-hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

And then your HTML:

```
<div id="message" class="is-hidden">
    Credit: <a href="#"> Link Three </a> <br>
    Credit: <a href="#"> Link Four </a>  <br>
</div>
```

And then your jQuery:

```
$('#message').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('is-hidden');
});
```